# Using fontello in iOS Tabbar image

Tags: ios, fontello

I need to use fontello custom icon along with title in tabbar. Is there any way to do that? I can use fontello text with in tab but not with title.

Comment: can't you export the custom icons as images?

Comment: I got these fonts from my client. Not sure if I will be able to get as an image